# How to export to extensionName in Powershell to CSV without additional characters?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to provide a report of info for admin accounts in a forest.  All admin accounts begin with admin.  The owner of the admin accounts has been added as the "extensionName" attribute in active directory and I want to include this in the report (and ideally then look up the owners manager in AD but this could be done in 2 parts).

The value returned seems to be a multiple so I need to select the first value for this but when I use `Select @{E={$_.extensionName[0]}}` the entry in the CSV file is shown as `@{$_.extensionName[0]=domain\username}` I want to exclude the `@{$_.extensionName[0]=` part

Any help would be very much appreciated as I am going in circles.

```
$AdminReport = "C:\Temp\AdminReport.CSV"
Remove-Item $AdminReport -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$STR = "Name,SAM,Enabled,Owner,Group Memberships"
Add-Content $AdminReport $STR
$AllUsersNow = Get-ADUser –Filter "SamAccountName -Like 'admin*'"
Foreach ($ThisUser in $AllUsersNow)
{

$NameOfUser = $ThisUser.UserPrincipalName
$SamOfUser = $ThisUser.SamAccountName
$DisabledOfUser = $ThisUser.Enabled
$ExtOfUser = Get-ADuser $ThisUser -Properties extensionName | Select @{E=        {$_.extensionName[0]}}
$GroupsOfUser = (Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $ThisUser).Name -join "; "

IF ($NameOfUser -like "*")
{

$STRNew = $NameOfUser+","+$SamOfUser+","+$DisabledOfUser+","+$ExtOfUser+","+$GroupsOfUser
Add-Content $AdminReport $STRNew
}
}
```

Actual output results show `@{$_.extensionName[0]=domain\username}` and I just want `domain\username`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with the extensionName attribute. You could just modify this one line of code:

```
$ExtOfUser = Get-ADuser $ThisUser -Properties extensionName | Select @{E=        {$_.extensionName[0]}}
```

To be the following:

```
$ExtOfUser = (Get-ADuser $ThisUser -Properties extensionName).extensionName
```

Or perhaps the following if extensionName is an array:

```
$ExtOfUser = (Get-ADuser $ThisUser -Properties extensionName).extensionName[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

It makes not much sense to manually build the csv file from strings as all data is present in objects.
Build a gathering [PSCustomObject] and export that.

```
## Q:\Test\2019\02\12\SO_54652780.ps1
$AdminReportFile = "C:\Temp\AdminReport.CSV"

$AdminReport = Foreach($User in (Get-ADUser –Filter "SamAccountName -Like 'xb*'")){
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name                = $User.UserPrincipalName
        SAM                 = $User.SamAccountName
        Enabled             = $User.Enabled
        Owner               = $User.ExtensionName|Select-Object -First 1
        'Group Memberships' = (Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $User).Name -join "; "
    }
}
$AdminReport
$AdminReport | Export-Csv $AdminReportFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: That is a much better way of doing it - thank you.   Although "$User.ExtensionName|Select-Object -First 1" returns a blank value so I used your code with ".....-Properties extensionName).extensionName[0]" from the other answer and that worked perfectly.